# Как сделать срез строки, который убирал бы 1-й и последний символ в этой строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Нужно сделать один срез строки, который удалял бы 1-й и последний символ в строке, не используя `len()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значения передаваемые в срезы могут быть отрицательными, в этом случае отсчет будет вестись с конца строки.

Чтобы получить строку без первого и последнего элемента, срез должен выглядеть так: `[1:-1]`

```
print("Hello World!"[1:-1])  # ello World
```

[**Пример**](https://repl.it/repls/TediousClearJavabytecode)

Comment: @MaxU, а там скобки стали обязательны?

Comment: В Python 3.x убрали оператор “print” и заменили его функцией «print()”. Вариант с функцией будет работать и в Python 2.x и в Python 3.x

Comment: @MaxU, ааа, понятно :-)

Comment: @MaxU, ссылку на пример тоже поменял, теперь 3.6

Answer (score 3):

Срез еще может быть описан как объект через [slice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice):

```
sl = slice(1, -1)
print("Hello World!"[sl])  # "ello World"
print("abc123"[sl])        # bc12
```